# Скрипты вне сборки webpack не видят jQuery, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

Есть собранный проект в webpack, при попытке кодера подключить новые скрипты, те не видят jQuery. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Перепишите скрипты без jQuery

Comment: Новые плагины тоже переписывать без  jQuery?